# How to insert values direct into zabbix Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, mariadb, zabbix

I need help with a Zabbix problem, I need to insert data with timestamp once in a day.

But I need to insert this data in the past moment

I have the algorithm to only brings me the number like ex:

Bring only the room number in data 08/27, but i need to insert this number into the Mysql (Maria DB) Database from zabbix.

The output will be like that:

```
data: 08/27     room: 12456     mobile:  9456 
data: 08/28     room: 13770     mobile: 10350 
data: 08/29     room: 10380     mobile: 11728 
data: 08/30     room: 14560     mobile:  5845
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a way to do it without using a file.

```
echo - Minutos_Sala ${convert[@]} ${room_minutes[$i]} | /usr/local/bin/zabbix_sender -z 127.0.0.1 -p 10051 -s "Host name" -T -i - -vv
```

With this command you can insert a Value In a specific date inside the zabbix trapper item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [trapper items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/trapper) and send values using [zabbix_sender](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manpages/zabbix_sender) command-line tool, like so:

```
$ echo '- room 1280000000 12456' | zabbix_sender -c /etc/zabbix_agentd.conf -T -i -
```

Option `-T` specifies that timestamps are provided in the input file and `1280000000` is the corresponding Unix timestamp.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for you help, but how can I specify to adjust just a dot in an time the zabbix_sender is add this value in the last 3 days even if with a timestamp configurated. 

I am using this command:
zabbix_sender -z 127.0.0.1 -T 1472688000 -s "Test Server" -k test -o 164332 -vv

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but you seem to be trying to specify the timestamp on the command line. However, according to `zabbix_sender -h`, the `-T` option says that timestamp is provided in the input file, so you should do it in a way similar to the answer.